# How to write client proxy for SPI and what the difference between client and server proxies?

Tags: hazelcast

I have developed own idGenerator based on Hazelcast `IdGenerator` class (with storing each `last_used_id` into db). Now I want to run hazelcast cluster as a single java application and my web-application as other app (web-application restart shouldn't move id values to next block). I move `MyIdGeneratorProxy` and `MyIdGeneratorService` to new application, run it, run web-application as a hazelcast-client and get

```
IllegalArgumentException: No factory registered for service: ecs:impl:idGeneratorService
```

It was okay when client and server were the same application.

It seems it's unable to process without some `clientProxy`. I have compared `IdGeneratorProxy` and `ClientIdGeneratorProxy` and it looks the same. What is the idea? How to write client proxy for services? I have found no documentation yet. Is direction of investigations correct? I thought it is possible to divide hazelcast inner services (like a id generator service) and my business-processes. Should I store custom ClientProxy (for custom spi) in my web-application?

Comment: You might want to look into snowcast (https://github.com/noctarius/snowcast) how I did it.

Comment: @noctarius you should answer with piece of code instead show me the link.

Comment: the reason why it was just a comment, to put a code example together I would have needed more time - at least it seemed to have helped at least so far that you could answer yourself

Comment: Thanks, @noctarius! Snowcast is a great project, it is not so easy to explore all code base of it in just a moment, but I am going to continue to try. May be some additional advices to complete my investigations? How do you learn it yourself?

Comment: Well I work for Hazelcast myself :) Currently the SPI is not really well documented and it can slightly change from time to time (as it did from 3.4.x to 3.5 - if you look at the latest commits you see I worked around it) therefore there is not yet a really good point to read about it, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a demo how to create a client proxy, the missing part `CustomClientProxy` function call, is quit complicated(more like a server proxy,here is called `ReadRequest`, the server is called `Operation`), you can find a how AtomicLong [implement](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-client/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/proxy/ClientAtomicLongProxy.java).For every client proxy method you have to make a request.

```
@Test
public void client() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    ClientConfig cfg = new XmlClientConfigBuilder("hazelcast-client.xml").build();
    ServiceConfig serviceConfig = new ServiceConfig();
    serviceConfig.setName(ConnectorService.NAME)
                 .setClassName(ConnectorService.class.getCanonicalName())
                 .setEnabled(true);
    ProxyFactoryConfig proxyFactoryConfig = new ProxyFactoryConfig();
    proxyFactoryConfig.setService(ConnectorService.NAME);
    proxyFactoryConfig.setClassName(CustomProxyFactory.class.getName());
    cfg.addProxyFactoryConfig(proxyFactoryConfig);
    HazelcastInstance hz = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(cfg);

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Connector c = hz.getDistributedObject(ConnectorService.NAME, "Connector:" + ThreadLocalRandom.current()
                                                                                                     .nextInt(10000));
        System.out.println(c.snapshot());
    }
}

private static class CustomProxyFactory implements ClientProxyFactory
{

    @Override
    public ClientProxy create(String id)
    {
        return new CustomClientProxy(ConnectorService.NAME, id);
    }
}

private static class CustomClientProxy extends ClientProxy implements Connector
{
    protected CustomClientProxy(String serviceName, String objectName)
    {
        super(serviceName, objectName);
    }

    @Override
    public ConnectorState snapshot()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadState(ConnectorState state)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean reconnect(HostNode node)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean connect()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

In hazelcast the IdGenerate is implemented as a wrapper for AtomicLong, you should implement you IdGenerate by you own, instead of extend IdGenerate.

So you have to implement these(more like a todo list XD):

```
API
interface MyIdGenerate
Server
MyIdGenerateService
MyIdGenerateProxy
MyIdGenerateXXXOperation
Client
ClientMyIdGenerateFactory
ClientMyIdGenerateProxy
MyIdGenerateXXXRequest
```

I also made a sequence(same as IdGenerate) [here](https://github.com/wenerme/seq), this is backed by zookeeper or redis,also it's easy to add a db backend,too.I will integrate to hazelcast if I got time.

Comment: Thank you, @wener, this approach works (you can remove definition of ServiceConfig instance, it is redundant there). Thank you for link to AtomicLong implementation. Now I try to extend existing [IdGenerator](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/3e9f88900ecd3009c4a3e641db7e5aaa14b60385/hazelcast-client/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/proxy/ClientIdGeneratorProxy.java) and there are no Operation-s. Do you have some ideas why? What should I do to read to understand this topic in a proper way?

Comment: There is no ReadRequest, because IdGenerator  is a wrapper for [ClientIAtomicLongProxy](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/3e9f88900ecd3009c4a3e641db7e5aaa14b60385/hazelcast-client/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/proxy/ClientAtomicLongProxy.java), you should check the IAtomicLong instead.