# What is required to configure Hazelcast java client to work with a User Defined Service?

Tags: java, xml, hazelcast

I have a user defined service that I made following chapter 24 of Hazelcast's documentation, but they never mention what is necessary to enable a client to access the distributed object using the getDistributedObject method of a Hazelcast Client Instance. My xml configuration is simply the default (very blank) xml with a serialization added. This is the configuration for my service using hazelcast node configuration:

```
<services enable-defaults="true">
    <service enabled="true">
        <name>MapManagerService</name>
        <class-name>com.ctl.hzl.service.MapManagerService</class-name>
    </service>
</services>
```

I'm using Hazelcast-client-3.10.1 and Java 1.8. I've been unable to find any formatting guidelines other than the xsi document, which has been useful but doesn't really show me what I need to include to support my service. I've gotten an error message in one of my tries that mentioned a service factory of some sort, which I think must be what I need, but I've been unable to find out what that requires. This is the schema location, if that's helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config
              http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-client-config-3.10.xsd">
```

Comment: Did you make your service implement com.hazelcast.spi.RemoteService as that is essential to make a service accessible to a client? Check out the documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.2/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-managedservice-and-remoteservice

Comment: Yes, the service implements both ManagedService and RemoteService in the ways described in the documentation with their example of a CounterService. It works properly across instances, but not clients. I think my problem is that I have not defined a factory type for my clients to use my service, and I'm currently looking for a way of doing so. I get this error if I run without defining my service in the client xml:  "No factory registered for service: MapManagerService"

Comment: I believe my question is a partial duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839563/how-to-write-client-proxy-for-spi-and-what-the-difference-between-client-and-ser , But they don't show how one defines a client-side service method request, nor how to configure the service via xml, which are two things I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
Giving access to user defined classes from client is not possible at the moment. This area needs more work to make this process user friendly.

This is the addition to answer here:
[How to write client proxy for SPI and what the difference between client and server proxies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839563/how-to-write-client-proxy-for-spi-and-what-the-difference-between-client-and-ser)

How to configure the service via xml:

```
<hazelcast-client>
<proxy-factories>
        <proxy-factory class-name="com.hazelcast.examples.ProxyXYZ1" service="sampleService1"/>
        <proxy-factory class-name="com.hazelcast.examples.ProxyXYZ2" service="sampleService1"/>
        <proxy-factory class-name="com.hazelcast.examples.ProxyXYZ3" service="sampleService3"/>
    </proxy-factories>
</hazelcast-client>
```

Request and response(called codecs) classes are generated via a different project called the hazelcast client protocol. The Readme.md from the client protocol project should help you with creating your own. 
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-client-protocol

One more important part is to implement and register a message task on the server. Message Tasks handle the requests coming from client. Unfortunately this part is not polished enough to make it SPI user friendly. A sample message task is as follows:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/impl/protocol/task/map/MapPutMessageTask.java

Comment: So, you're saying that I can't get an actual instance of the service, but I can get a proxy instance and activate the methods of an existing service object remotely? If so, that still works for my case, which would be spectacular.

Comment: I think my answer is misunderstood. Unfortunately, this feature is not usable at the moment unless you fork and change the hazelcast code yourself. 
Registering your own messageTask from outside of hazelcast is not possible at the moment.
To make it accessible via SPI, we need to work on it a little bit more.